# need help setting QueueMessageEncoding.Base64 for new Azure queueClient version

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-queues

Recently updated to current library 12.8 for azure queue processing.
Inserted message no longer work on existing routines as they are encoded as UTF-8 vs Base 64.

found the thread talking about this and see that MS has implemented a new method to set encoding.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10242

I am unable to set the encoding however and just need a push in the right direction.
This is a .NEt 4.8 Console Application
code I am currently using:

```
        private static void insertQueueMessage(string messageToInsert, string queueName)
    {
        // Get the connection string from app settings
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];

        // Instantiate a QueueClient which will be used to create and manipulate the queue
        QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName);

        // Send a message to the queue
        queueClient.SendMessage(messageToInsert);

    }
```

What I have tried:

```
queueClient.SendMessage(messageToInsert,QueueMessageEncoding.Base64);
```

and

`QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName,QueueMessageEncoding.Base64);`

How do I code this to work?

Comment: I posted the answer, thank you @GauravMantri

Answer (score 4):

Stupid easy answer, I feel like a dolt missing this.

```
            QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName, new QueueClientOptions
        {
            MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.Base64
        });
```